# CentOS 6: bond 3 NICs with different modes (1+4)

Tags: linux-networking, centos6, bonding

On my CentOS 6 box I would like to construct the following setup:

```
.----------------------.
|       Switch         |
'-=------------------=-'
  |       |       | 
  |       |       | 
.-=----.--=---.---=--.
| eth0 | eth1 | eth2 |
|-------------|------|
|    mode 4   |
'--------------------'
|    active-backup   |
'--------------------'
```

NICs eth0 and eth1 are 2 10 Gbit/s NICs and currently configured as mode 4. In order to prevent network loss on their failure, I would like to add eth2 (1 Gbit/s NIC) as active-backup.

Since it is not possible to have a bond with a bond, are there other ways I can make this work? 
The goal is to have 1 IP among the 3 NICs and ideally keep the mode 4 bond for eth0+1.

Comment: You can put as many nics into a mode 4 bond as you wish.  The active-backup would depend on your switch topology and if you have multiple partner addresses or a single mlag.  You would not be able to put a bond inside of a bond; at least, not in the way you described.  The bonding driver needs to talk to physical devices.  Add a second switch, and you will have the setup you described.

Comment: But for mode 4 all the NICs would have to have the same speed, wouldn't they? We are currently thinking about a mode 6 bond of all 3 - it does not give the best per-process bandwidth, but it should work for us (many users with many transfers).

Comment: mode 4 speed is based on the lag grouping and slowest speed of any nic.  So if your group of 2 is active, you will have xor 2gb/s.  I've not had much experience with mode 6.